# JPA Mapping of Many to Many with Additional Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm not even sure this is really a M2M relationship, but I'll describe it and hopefully someone can help with the mapping:

```
@Entity
public class EntityOne {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    // other properties
}
```

I need to map this as a parent/child relationships with some additional data that goes along with each row. For example:

`parent_entity_one_id  |  child_entity_one_id  |  some_boolean_property
100                   |  200                  |  false
100                   |  201                  |  false
100                   |  202                  |  true
101                   |  300                  |  false
102                   |  301                  |  false
103                   |  302                  |  true`

I've tried with some `@ManyToMany` mappings but that only seems appropriate when the relationship is between 2 entities; like User & Role for example. But I'd like for `parent_entity_one_id` and `child_entity_one_id` to be a composite key is possible.

Comment: I saw that answer and I believe it is different. Again, as I mentioned, the typical M2M references 2 tables. This is referencing a parent/child relationship with the single entity.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Post the entities with the relationships you hope to achieve.

Comment: @AlanHay I'm not sure I can be more clear in that I actually did show the entity that I'm working with in addition to the structure that I hope to achieve with the mappings I'm having an issue with. That said, I've solved the problem and will post an answer soon.

Comment: Well, as it turns out, I can't post an answer because folks think this is a duplicate even though it isn't.